# Chef still looking for deleted recipe during chef-client run

Tags: chef-infra, ubuntu-16.04, devops

I have deleted a Chef recipe by deleting the recipe `.rb` file all references to it and then uploading the cookbook(s) it belongs to with:

`knife cookbook upload crmpicco` and `knife cookbook upload crmpicco-deploy`

I then baked the server to pull in the changes (`chef-client -l error`) and when I do this I see the recipe listed in the list of recipes.

```
chef-client -l error
Starting Chef Client, version 12.19.36
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["ulimit2", "logrotate::global", "users::sysadmins", "apt", "postfix", "redisio", "redisio::enable", "etcd", "apache2", "newrelic::php_agent", "crmpicco-deploy::maintenance", "crmpicco-deploy::enrich", "crmpicco-deploy"]
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
...
```

The recipe `"crmpicco-deploy::enrich"` is the one I deleted, but for some reason it's still listed in the run list.

The inevitable error from this is:

```
Installing Cookbook Gems:
Compiling Cookbooks...

================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error
================================================================================

Chef::Exceptions::RecipeNotFound
--------------------------------
could not find recipe enrich for cookbook crmpicco-deploy

Platform:
---------
x86_64-linux
```

Is there a cache or another command I need to run to force through the removal of this recipe?

Comment: Does `knife cookbook show crmpicco <version> recipes` show this recipe `enrich.rb` as well? Speaking of version - it would be a good idea to update (and use the new) cookbook versions when making such changes.

Comment: @Seshadri_C Thanks for the comment. No, the recipe is not shown when I run the command above on my local machine. Is there some sort of cache that needs flushed?

Answer (score 0):

Adding this as an answer as it might need some explanation.

It is probably picking up same from the `Recipes:` section that shows up in `knife node show <nodename>`.

**OPTION 1:**

1. Override the existing run list using `chef-client -o`:

   ```
   chef-client -o "recipe[crmpicco],recipe[crmpicco-deploy]" -l error
   ```

**OPTION 2:**

You could try running `chef-client` after "emptying" the `run_list` for node. This should remove the "saved" `Recipes:` for the node.

1. Edit the node:

   ```
   knife node edit NODENAME
   ```
2. Note down the recipes/roles from under `"run_list":`, remove them and save the node so that the `run_list` is empty.

   ```json
     "run_list": [

     ]
   ```
3. Do a `chef-client` run and it should report that the node "has an empty run list".
4. Check that the node's `Recipes:` is now blank by using:

   ```
   knife node show NODENAME -a 'recipes'
   ```
5. Edit the node again and and add the roles/recipes back in `run_list`, save the node.
6. Run `chef-client -l error`

*Update:*

It is always a good practice to change / update cookbook versions when making any changes and use the newer version of cookbook in the run. It can ensure that the `chef-client` will pull the newer cookbook to the node - which in this case will be without a reference to the missing recipe file.

Answer (score 0):

You must remove this recice from the run list too.

If you use policyfile to manage run lists, then you need to remove the recipe from that policy and push (`chef push`) it to Chef Server.

If you set run_list in node attributes (the old way, before policies were introduced), then run:

```rb
knife node edit <node>
```

and remove the recipe from the run_list.